# How do I create an SSRS Tablix that has blank rows for each day of the year?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to start with a blank table that has 365 rows with the first column showing the date (starting with today) and then incrementing with one row for each day. The Tablix will only have 4 columns - date, inbound, outbound and total. I'm using a LOOKUP function that will check the date of an inbound order and drop that number in the inbound column of the row with the corresponding date. Same thing with the outbound values but that looks at a different dataset. The last column will just calculate the remaining balance.

Comment: Please share what you've researched so far, what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no functionality in SSRS to generate rows in a table other than using a query.

Here's a query to generate the dates. It would be better if you could add the logic for the LOOKUP in the query rather than in SSRS - the LOOKUP function is somewhat slow.

```
DECLARE @START_DATE DATE = GETDATE() 
DECLARE @END_DATE  DATE  = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE() -1)

;WITH GETDATES AS  
    (  
        SELECT @START_DATE AS THEDATE
        UNION ALL  
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1, THEDATE) FROM GETDATES  
        WHERE THEDATE < @END_DATE  
)

SELECT * FROM GETDATES 
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Comment: PERFECT!!! I wish I had the skills to code the query but I have 2 different databases and one of them the table is populated on a stored procedure so i dont see the graphical interface of tables and JOINs. So for now I just have the blank table you created and will use the LOOKUP function to match an item that has a date received or date shipped value that matches the date in the blank table. Then there is a row that keeps a running total. The last column will calculate a "reorder date" based on inventory levels.